# How to skip the VS Code Get Started walkthrough in code-server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-server

The code-server view always directs to the VS Code Get Started walkthrough at the start when I open it on an incognito window.
I tried adding `"workbench.startupEditor": "none"` to both `User/settings.json` and `workspace settings.json` but still it results in the walkthrough page on a new incognito window.
Is there a setting or a way in VS Code or code-server to skip the 'Get Started with VS Code' walkthrough?
[image]